How do I fix Rust's "std::fmt::Display" not implemented error on a Vec<String>?
So I am trying to create an argument-processing library. It currently looks like this:
pub mod utility {
    use std::env;
    pub fn argument_processing() {
        let arg:Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
        let arguments: &[String] = &arg[..]; // suspected culprit
        println!("Supplied arguments: {}", arguments);
    }
}


The error:
`[String]` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `[String]`, which is required by `&[String]: std::fmt::Display`
in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead.

My ambition is to make the program accept an arbitrary amount of arguments.
Any fixes (and alternatives) for this problem?
I have tried to:

Format the string (failed)
Unborrow the &arg[..] (failed)
Replace the [..] with [n] (n = a value) (succeed, but not desired)


The compiler suggests that you change {} to {:?} - have you tried that?
